# Does the github.com GUI support syncing a derived repository to a specific commit on the base repository

Tags: git, github

[image]To make this concrete, my derived repository, which also sits on github.com trails behind the base repository.  When the base repository has a release and changes the version number I desire to sync to that point rather than syncing every day or every hour.  If the bump to version number actually reflects some increased amount of testing on the part of the owner of the base repository this will minimize my QA burden.  But even if it doesn't daily changes unnerve my customers who prefer the illusion of a stable release schedule and so on.

I was recently on vacation so I missed a release and I need some of its features.  The base repository sometimes makes a branch for a release and sometimes doesn't and there wasn't a new branch last month.  When I try to generate a pull request on github.com, using compare across forks to swap the direction, I get the option to merge all the missing changes.  If I try to paste in the commit that I want then I, in the GUI, lose the ability to create a pull request from the base repository to my repository.

Due to GPL it's extremely important that I have my own publicly accessible repository on Github that reflects what I ship.  I make changes and only some of them are accepted upstream because my customers have an unusual usage scenario.  So it isn't an option to just pull down what I want at the command line in Linux and point the customers at the base repository.  But it strikes me that I'm not the only person with this situation so there's probably a simple solution that I'm unaware of.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT this can't be solved at the GUI so I did what I needed to using a clone from the base repository in a detached head state at the Unix command line.  Git at the command line is very powerful but it seems that the github GUI is very limited. I will close this question since I've got a solution.